Аналог enumerate в GDScript
Есть ли в GDScript аналог питоновкого enumerate?
Я могу сделать так:
i = 0

for elem in array:
    # сделать что-то
    id += 1

Но этот метод выглядит совершенно некрасиво.
Есть какой-то более красивый способ?

Можно перебирать только индексы, а затем уже брать элемент с таким индексом.
Это делается так:
for i in array.size():
    elem = array[i]
    # сделать что-то

